# Is the take function well defined on a Scala Map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, take

Is the `take` function safe to use on a Scala `Map`? I thought that `Map`s were unordered, so that `myMap.take(2)` would return 2 random elements of `myMap`. But testing on the interpreter makes me feel that it is safe:

```
scala> val z = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30, 4 -> 40)
z: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30, 4 -> 40)

scala> z.take(2)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20)

scala> z.take(2)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20)

scala> z.take(2)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20)

scala> z.take(2)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20)
```

So, is it safe to use `take` on a `Map`, or do I need to use a `ListMap`?

Comment: You are asking us whether `take` is "well-defined" and "safe". The only way that we can answer this question is if you give a precise, unambiguous, complete, objective, verifiable definition of what *exactly* you mean by "well-defined" and "safe". I am reasonably sure that it will not erase your harddrive, for example, does that count as "safe"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll very likely get the same 2 every time you `take(2)`, but there's no telling which 2 you'll get in the first place.

```
val y = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30, 4 -> 40, 5 -> 5)
y.take(2)  //res0: Map[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 5, 1 -> 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, you might want to consider using a `SortedMap`, which guarantees that keys are sorted in order. Consider the following two examples in the *Scala REPL*:

```scala
scala> val z = Map(4 -> 40, 3 -> 30, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20)
z: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(4 -> 40, 3 -> 30, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20)

scala> z.take(2)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(4 -> 40, 3 -> 30)

scala> import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

scala> val zs = SortedMap(4 -> 40, 3 -> 30, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20)
zs: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30, 4 -> 40)

scala> zs.take(2)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20)
```

As @jwvh pointed out, in a regular `Map` there's no defined ordering, but that ordering is fixed once defined, so you're always going to get the same members returned for `.take(2)` given the same map instance. However, which values you get returned will depend upon the order in which the map was created.

Meanwhile, in a `SortedMap`, the keys are always ordered, so that when you employ `.take(2)` elements, you will always get the same two elements, regardless of the definition order: those that have the two lowest key values.

Refer to the [help on the `take` method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/SortedMap.html#take(n:Int):Repr) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable maps in Scala have special subtypes for 0 to 4 elements, which [you can see in the code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L95-L213), as an optimization. As it happens, `Map.apply` with up to 4 arguments produces an instance of one of these classes, so iterating it will always produce elements in the order passed to `Map.apply`.

Comment: Excellent observation, but I don't think that is guaranteed behavior and could possibly change (though unlikely) with a future Scala release.

Comment: @jwvh Yes, I should have mentioned this.

Answer (score -1):

> Is the take function well defined on a Scala Map?

This depends on your exact definition of "well-defined", but I would argue that, yes, for most common interpretations of "well-defined", it is well-defined.

[The documentation](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#take(n:Int):Repr) lists all possible outcomes for all possible inputs clearly, and there are no ambiguous or unspecified inputs. All corner cases are covered:

- If the collection has less than `n` elements, the whole collection will be returned.
- If `n` is negative, an empty collection will be returned.
- If the collection is un-ordered, arbitrary elements will be returned.

> Is the `take` function safe to use on a Scala `Map`?

This depends on your exact definition of "safe", but I would argue that, yes, for most common interpretations of "safe", it is safe.

- It is statically type-safe.
- It is dynamically type-safe.
- It does not throw an exception.

> I thought that `Map`s were unordered, so that `myMap.take(2)` would return 2 random elements of `myMap`.

No. The documentation says:

> Note: might return different results for different runs, unless the underlying collection type is ordered.

This means that arbitrary elements will be returned, not random ones.